# Zendesk authentication

Tags: javascript, authentication, chat, zendesk, zendesk-api

I need to display user's name in the in the zendesk chat ( for the agents), I'm using the code provided by zendesk:

```
window.zESettings = {
 webWidget: {
   authenticate: {
     chat: {
       jwtFn: function(callback) { 
         fetch('JWT_TOKEN_ENDPOINT').then(function(res) {
            res.text().then(function(jwt) {
             callback(jwt);
            });
          });
        }
      } 
    }
  }
};
```

and jwt token is:

```
var payload = {
  name: '#{customerName}',
  email: '#{customerEmail}',
  iat: #{timestamp},
  external_id: '#{externalId}'
};
var token = jwt.sign(payload, '#{yourSecret}');
```

The code doesn't work, I don't get errors but user name is not visible. Zendesk documentation doesn't provide any valuable information, has anyone integrated Zendesk in their app? What am I doing wrong? any help and suggestion is greatly appreciated.

Comment: did you find the solution? During the integration I faces with similar issue, I did all the steps described here https://support.zendesk.com/hc/en-us/articles/4408838925082 but at the end just response: {
 "success": false,
 "error": "not entitled to visitor auth"
}

Answer (score 0):

I'm running into some issues with a similar implementation. In my situation I am using the same Javascript to authenticate the chat webWidget. I have my `JWT_TOKEN_ENDPOINT` defined in a rails controller (RoR) which uses the `ruby-jwt` gem to generate the token.

In my case though, my browser is showing the error message:

```
Zendesk Chat Web SDK: Error: init: Failed to verify token: jwt verification error
```

Are you seeing any browser console errors to suggest what might be the issue?

Do you have your endpoint setup to generate the JWT token?

Are you passing a valid shared secret in the `jwt.sign(payload, "#{youSecret}")` var assignment?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that timestamp is in seconds, without floating points.

Use `iat: Math.round(Date.now() / 1000)`